# jolt, Transforming Flatten List of Key/Value to Array of name, value

Tags: jolt

I have a dynamic list of flatten key value pairs and need to convert it to an array of objects with name and value elements.

Input

```
{
"something_Y":"somevalue",
"something_X" :"someOtheValue",
"st":"sv",
.
.
.
}
```

and for the expected result should be

```
{
 "array":[
{
"name":something_Y",
"value":"somevalue"
},
{
"name":something_X",
"value":"someOtherValue"
},
{
"name":"st",
"value":"sv"
},
.
.
.
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is "style" of problem has an example provided on jolt demo site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#mapToList

An adaptation of this for your data would be:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        //  #2 means go three levels up the tree (count from 0),
        //  and ask the "root" node, how many of it's
        //  children have been matched.
        //
        // This allows us to put the name and the value into
        //  the same object in the "array" array.
        "$": "array[#2].name",
        "@": "array[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```